# Iterating through a panda column to assign events

Tags: python, pandas, iterator

Suppose I've a list like `[0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0]`.

Whenever the iterator encounters a 1, the preceding list including the 1 is assigned to one single event. This continues till the next 1 is encountered. 
So, in this case, there are 2 events.

But if the list is like `[0,0,1,1,0,0,1]`, this would still count as 2 events, since consecutive 1's are considered together.

As of now, I'm excluding cases like `[1,0,0,1]`.

A new column can be created to reflected if the left 0 or 1 belongs to which event, like Event 1 or Event 2 etc.

I found some approached which uses `zip` but my situation is somewhat different. How do I approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, to define an event:

- it must start from 0(??), end with '1' and must have at least one '1'
- if two adjacent rows are

  - from 0->0, 1->1, 0->1, then in the same event
  - from 1->0, different events

Following I am using the `(df.c.diff() < 0).cumsum()+1` to identify the event_id and adjust the last *event_id* group based on if any '1' exhibits:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

l = [0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0]
df = pd.DataFrame(l, columns=['c'])

# event_id changes when df.c.diff() < 0
event_id = (df.c.diff() < 0).cumsum()+1

#event_id
#Out[233]: 
#0    1
#1    1
#2    1
#3    1
#4    1
#5    2
#6    2
#7    2
#8    3

# the last event_id sequence might not be an event if it does not contain any '1'
m1 = df.groupby(event_id).c.transform(max) == 1
# if you need at least one '0' in an event, then adjust condition to m1&m2 in np.where() and since the first event_id might be skipped thus its calculation should be based on if the first row is an '1'
#event_id = (df.c.diff() < 0).cumsum()+ np.where(df.c.iloc[0]==1,0,1)
#m2 = df.groupby(event_id).c.transform(min) == 0
#df['event'] = np.where(m1&m2, event_id.map('Event-{}'.format), 'Not an event')

df['event'] = np.where(m1, event_id.map('Event-{}'.format), 'Not an event')
# df
# Out[235]: 
#   c         event
#0  0       Event-1
#1  0       Event-1
#2  0       Event-1
#3  1       Event-1
#4  1       Event-1
#5  0       Event-2
#6  0       Event-2
#7  1       Event-2
#8  0  Not an event
```

**Note:** `df.groupby(event_id).c.transform(max) == 1` means at least one '1' are in the same event_id group and thus qualified for an event.

Answer (score 1):

You can just using `itertools.groupby`

```
import itertools 
l=[0,0,1,1,0,0,1]
[list(y)[0]==1 for x , y in itertools.groupby(l)]
Out[853]: [False, True, False, True]
sum([list(y)[0]==1 for x , y in itertools.groupby(l)])
Out[854]: 2
```